# Xamarin Forms iOS application always runs on simulator even if I choose a device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I ported my Xamarin Forms project from windows to Mac and I am trying to run it on a connected device which is added in the provisioning profile (provisioning profile and identity is setup accordingly in IOS Bundle Signing settings).

Whenever I try to run the App using Debug|iPhone > my Iphone:

[image]

It starts simulator runs on that instead of the device :

[image]

After stopping the build if I go back to Bundle Signing settings its changed back to simulator automatically:

[image]

I am using following setup:

Visual Studio 2017 Community on Mac  7.2 preview build 540.

XCode 8.3.3

Can anyone please help me with proper configuration to run the app on IPhone?

Many Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of messing around I finally found the problem and solution.

In solution settings, iOS project (Debug-iPhone) configuration was mapped to (Debug|Simulator).

Simply changed it to Debug|iPhone and Its working fine now.